# Weird Behaviour when initiate a class

Tags: c#, inheritance, initialization

I'm working on a game, and I made all the building blocks. now I'm working on the game logic and rendering.
I have abstract Monster class and a class call GreenMonster that inherits from it.

Now the weird thing is, when I try to init a GreenMonster object.

when I do this:

```
private void initGreenMonsters()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < greenMonsters.Length; i++)
        {
            greenMonsters[i] = new GreenMonster(new Point(0,40),new Size(40, 40));
        }
    }
```

every thing works like I planned and I can render the images on the form.

but when I try to init like that:

```
private void initGreenMonsters()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < greenMonsters.Length; i++)
        {

            greenMonsters[i] = new GreenMonster();
            greenMonsters[i].Position = new Point(0, 40);
            greenMonsters[i].Size = new Size(40, 40);
        }
    }
```

I don't get any errors, and the app runs, but I can render the monsters.

This is the Monster class constructor and the Draw Method I use to draw a Monster:

```
 public Monster(Point _startPosition,Size _size)
    {
        this.size = _size;
        this.position = _startPosition;
    }

 public virtual void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        Rectangle monsterRec = new Rectangle(position, size);
        g.DrawImage(img, monsterRec);
    }
```

and this is the GreenMonster class constructor:

```
public GreenMonster(Point _startPosition, Size _size)
        : base(_startPosition, _size)
    {
        this.img = new Bitmap(SpaceInvadersGame.Properties.Resources.NormalMonster);
        this.hp = 1;
        this.speed = 1;
    }

public GreenMonster()
    {
        this.img = new Bitmap(SpaceInvadersGame.Properties.Resources.NormalMonster);
        this.hp = 1;
        this.speed = 1;
    }
```

the only thing that bothers me is, that when I'm looking at both ways I init the objects, it just looks the same..
I just can't find any different between in both of the ways.
someone have any idea how its different?

If you need more code so the question is more clear, I would be happy to add!

this is the Monster class and its properties
    public abstract class  Monster
    {
        protected Point position;
        public Point Position { get { return position; } set { position = value; } }

```
    protected Size size;
    public Size Size { get { return size; } set { value = size; } }

    public int speed;

    protected Bitmap img;

    protected int hp;
    public int HP { get { return hp; } }



    public void SetStartingPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        this.position = new Point(x, y);
    }


    public virtual void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        Rectangle monsterRec = new Rectangle(position, size);
        g.DrawImage(img, monsterRec);
    }
```

}

Comment: There must be a second constructor for GreenMonster, or your code would not compile. Can you post it?

Comment: yes there is i will add it now!

Comment: So what are the Position and Size properties? Maybe posting your code as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Comment: What does the base constructor `Monster()` do when the size is zero or undefined?  Maybe it does something unfortunate that the `Size` setter does not fix.

Comment: You need to post all of your code as @nvoigt says. It seems like there is a problem with property setters. The constructors are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your incoming value to the current size, rather than setting the current size to the incoming value, in the method below:

```
public Size Size { get { return size; } set { value = size; } }
```

should be

```
public Size Size { get { return size; } set { size = value; } }
```

Your code for `Position` looks OK though:

```
public Point Position { get { return position; } set { position = value; } }
```